# Weblogic + Spring Boot Cloud Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey, weblogic12c

I am trying to run a Spring Boot Cloud Eureka server under a Weblogic webserver (Java 8, Weblogic 12, and Spring boot parent 2.4.13). I configured my pom to generate a war file and I am able to deploy but, as soon as it starts I get these errors:

````
2022-03-03 18:46:34.013 ERROR 5108 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.jerseyFilterRegistration(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:185)

The following method did not exist:

    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V

The method's class, com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer, is available from the following locations:

    zip:D:/Development/Domains/lifeGateway/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/registrationServer/rh50eu/war/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.4.jar!/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.class
    jar:file:/D:/Development/Servers/WebLogic12213/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/weblogic.jaxrs.portable.server.jar!/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer: file:/D:/Development/Servers/WebLogic12213/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/weblogic.jaxrs.portable.server.jar
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet: file:/D:/Development/Servers/WebLogic12213/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet: file:/D:/Development/Servers/WebLogic12213/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

<Mar 3, 2022 6:46:34,271 PM CET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1291493286977307" for task "2" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.jerseyFilterRegistration(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
<Mar 3, 2022 6:46:34,315 PM CET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application "registrationServer" on [partition-name: DOMAIN].>
<Mar 3, 2022 6:46:34,327 PM CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "registrationServer".>
<Mar 3, 2022 6:46:34,327 PM CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.<init>(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Application;)V
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.jerseyFilterRegistration(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:185)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace```

After some investigations, I start to think it is related to the embedded tomcat but, I am not sure. At the moment I am stuck, do you have any idea why I am getting this error? 

These are the dependencies I am including:

```<dependencies>

        <!-- 1. Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 2. Spring Boot Starter Cloud -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 3. Spring Boot Starter Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 4. Spring Boot Starter Modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- 5. Servlet Starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the issue. There were some dependencies conflicts (in particular Jersey and FasterXml Jackson deps) that must be resolved in order to start the Eureka service under Weblogic.

So, I have changed the pom.xml in this way:

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

```
<!-- 1. Spring Boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- 2. Spring Boot Starter Cloud -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.eureka/eureka-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
    <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.17</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>


<!-- 3. Spring Boot Starter Web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- 4. Spring Boot Starter Modules -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- 5. Servlet Starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- 6. Resolving conflicts with dependecies -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.sun.jersey}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>${com.sun.jersey}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <version>${jackson-dataformat-xml}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.fasterxml.woodstox}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.servo</groupId>
    <artifactId>servo-core</artifactId>
    <version>${com.netflix.servo}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to be sure that your target packaging type is `war`. Check out your `pom.xml`
2. Add `ServletInitializer`

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebLogicApplication.class);
    }

}
```

3. Add `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` as `provided` depedency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

These should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, both are done.

Answer (score 1):

i think to work with weblogic, there are two files needed to be putted under WEB-INF

1. weblogic.xml
2. dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml

the contents of weblogic as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
    http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:context-root>/myweb</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

the content of dispatcherServlet-servlet.xml as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found same issue and can fixed by update jersey version follow
[Updating the Version of Jersey JAX-RS RI](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/version.htm#RESTF203)

Edit file `weblogic.xml` in **webapp/WEB-INF**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.5/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

<wls:context-root>/</wls:context-root>
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        
        <!-- jersey-bundle-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- Jackson-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jettison-*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- jsr311*.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>

        <!-- asm.jar -->
        <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>

</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

And not edit file `pom.xml`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).